# How do I read a file into a list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, streamreader

I have a project to create a phone book of sorts. It needs to read a file and output the name to a list box in the main form. When the user selects a name a new form should open with the name phone number and email address.

Currently there are no syntax errors, but the program does not read the file. It always throws an exception. The file name is on my desktop and I verified the file name matches the code. Any insight on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<PersonEntry> nameList = new List<PersonEntry>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    class PersonEntry
    {
        public string _name { get; set; }
        public string _number { get; set; }
        public string _email { get; set; }

    }

    private void GetNamesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Readfile();
        DisplayNameList();
    }

    private void Readfile()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line;
            char[] deliminator = { ';' };
            inputFile = File.OpenText("Personlist.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Use class
                PersonEntry entry = new PersonEntry();
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                string[] tokens = line.Split(deliminator);

                entry._name = tokens[0];
                entry._number = tokens[1];
                entry._email = tokens[2];
                nameList.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file");
        }
    }

    private void DisplayNameList()
    {
        //Add the entry objects to the List
        foreach (PersonEntry nameDisplay in nameList)
        {
            namesListBox.Items.Add(nameDisplay._name);
        }
    }
    public void namesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (namesListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Get full info for the selected item in the list
            string name = nameList[namesListBox.SelectedIndex]._name;
            string email = nameList[namesListBox.SelectedIndex]._email;
            string phone = nameList[namesListBox.SelectedIndex]._number;

            //Create second form for these details
            DetailForm f2 = new DetailForm(name, email, phone);

            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Name.");
        }
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the exception

Comment: It just shows the exception message I listed. There are no syntax errors, it just doesn't read the text from the file.

Comment: catch the exception object and look at the error message `catch(Exceptoin e){e.message...}`

Comment: Where is the file located relative to your application? Is it in the same folder? You may want to consider fully qualifying the path (either absolutely or relatively). I'd recommend placing a breakpoint to try and see _where_ your application is attempting to read the file from.

Comment: get rid of the `try/catch` so you can see what's breaking

Comment: The file was on my desktop, I moved it into the project file and still nothing.

Comment: I was told once. But I figured it out. Try to be nicer to people.

Comment: I count three times. Twice by me in my prior comment, and once by RufusL. I am being nice. I'm trying to get you some help by getting you to focus on doing something that will **actually help**, and you seem to be intent on doing everything **except** what will actually get you help. Try to be polite when peiople are trying to help you, and try listening to what they're telling you.

Answer (score 0):

File is not in correct folder, exception shows correct file location. After moving it the application works as intended.